# There went something wrong when identifying duplicates

Tags: discussion

The question [Need Query for th problem in oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/need-query-for-th-problem-in-oracle) was identified as duplicate of [Need query for the below problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78759/need-query-for-the-below-problem). If one reads the title one can be almost sure it must be the same query but I am not sure if one should see it as duplicates because the first query is a little bit more complex and generally it returns more than one row. But even more strange is that the second question is marked as duplicate of a third question [How do I create a user-defined aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/how-do-i-create-a-user-defined-aggregate-function). The second question is tagged "oracle" the third one is tagged "mysql". The second question asks for a select statement the third query asks how to implement a "user defined aggregate function". That does not really make sense to say a question is a duplicate because one possible (poor) answer is the answer of a completely different question.

Comment: Going for the title and tags alone, then yes, it can be difficult to notice how those questions are duplicated. But if you see the close message, it says: "This question already has an answer here". And if you look at the most upvoted answer on the third question, you'll see that it answers the fisrst question posted here, the second one and the third one (for MySQL and Oracle)

Comment: @Lamak: You did not read the close message carefully enough. 
It says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer". Maybe the answer of ypercube to the third question is an answer to the second one but nevertheless the second question is not the same third question.
Actually the answer of ypercube is not an answer to the third question. 
Also the accepted answer of third question is unusable for the fist and second question, 
because the first and second question are different form the third one.